# Show that evaluation is continuous on $C[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, normed-spaces

Choose and fix a point $c \in [0,1]$, and consider the function $E: C[0,1] \rightarrow R $ given by $E(f) = f(c)$. Show that $E$ is continuous.

My question is what does fix a point mean and what is $E(f)$.

Comment: It just means pick some fixed point $c$ and define the 'evaluation' operator that takes a function and returns the value of the function evaluated at that point. So, for example, if $c = {1 \over 2}$ and $f(x) = x^2$, then $E(f) = f({1 \over 2}) = {1 \over 2^2}$.

Comment: that make sense. but i dont know how to start the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $\|f-g\| < \epsilon$ then $|f(c)-g(c)| < \epsilon$.

To elaborate slightly: $|E(f)-E(g)| \le \| f-g \|$, hence $E$ is Lipschitz
continuous.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear which topology you have on $C[0,1]$.

1. if we have the maximum-norm $\|*\|_{\infty}$ on $C[0,1]$,then $E$ is  continuous.
2. if we have the $L^1$-norm $\|*\|_{1}$ on $C[0,1]$,then $E$ is not continuous.

Comment: sorry, it's the maximum-norm. I dont know how to start with the proof.